# jQuery Image rollover changes all images on the page

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to change an image with its alternative one on hover. I've got the second image as an HTML attribute and just want to swap them with jQuery but somehow when I hover over an image, all product images are being changed with the current alternative one.

My HTML structure is as follows:

```
<div class="product-tile">
    <div class="product-image">
        <a class="thumb-link" href="#">
            <img src="images/currentImage" data-alternative-img="images/altImg" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the jQuery code:

```
$('.tiles-container .product-tile').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this).find('.thumb-link img');

    if ($this.data().alternativeImg) {
        var img = $this.attr('src');
        var altImg = $this.attr('data-alternative-img');

        $this.on({
            mouseenter: function() {
                $this.attr('src', altImg);
                $this.attr('data-alternative-img', img);
            },
            mouseleave: function() {
                $this.attr('src', img);
                $this.attr('data-alternative-img', altImg);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I've played around with this code in the console and the image is being taken correctly, also the if-statement is working as it should and both attributes (src and data-alternative-img) are with their correct value. There probably is something wrong with the changing of the attributes which I couldn't figure out for 2 days now, as the image is being replaced everywhere, so any pointing to the right direction would be very much appreciated.

Comment: why do you need to loop through it? You can pick a common selector and attach event handler and then use `this` to target current element.

Comment: This is what I tried initially, but the behavior was the same and I thought that I should loop through each element in order to catch them more specifically. No luck however

Comment: use `mouseover` and `mouseout` for your hover events ,also instead of `.attr('data-alternative-img')` use `.data('alternative-img')`

Comment: Thanks, definitely will have something to read later for these differences, but still doesn't fix the existing problem.

Comment: Is the image that you get for all images on hover, the last one?

Comment: No, actually it takes only the first data-alternative-img available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `.each` function you can directly write `mouseenter/mouseleave` function

```
<div class="product-tile">
    <div class="product-image">
        <a class="thumb-link" href="#">
            <img src="images/currentImage" data-mouseenter-img="images/altImg" data-mouseout-img="images/currentImage" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

$('.product-tile').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        var $this = $(this).find('.thumb-link img');
        if($this.data().mouseenter-img) {
            $this.attr('src', $this.data('mouseenter-img'));
        }
    }, 
    mouseleave: function() {
        var $this = $(this).find('.thumb-link img');
        if($this.data().mouseout-img) {
            $this.attr('src', $this.data('mouseout-img'));
        }   
    }
});
```

Comment: What would `$(this)` refer to if this code is not inside each loop?

Comment: Yes, `$(this)` would refer to the window as it would not be bound to anything.

Comment: Could you please explain why we need a data-mouseout-img when it is the same as the src and they're both cached variables in my code?

Comment: if you use `mouseout-img` then no need to set set two variable (img, altImg) every time.

Comment: Works like charm, thanks for the extra optimisation. Cheers!